# How to fix issue during project starting for Qt for Android

Tags: android, c++, qt

I am trying to create Android app in Qt creator. When I try to create a sample app using the online documentation on [Qt's website](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/qt-creator-accelbubble-example.html), the project never gets created properly. It gives the following error message :
`/bin/sh: 1: /root/Android/Sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++: not found

Project ERROR: Cannot run target compiler '/root/Android/Sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++'.

Output:/bin/sh: 1: /root/Android/Sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++: not found
Maybe you forgot to setup the environment?

Error while parsing file /home/aditya/Programs/Office_Work/android_test/android_test.pro. Giving up.`

For the setup I installed the latest Android SDK by installing Android Studio following [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/android-getting-started.html#testing-your-setup) documentation on Qt's website. I installed multiple API versions through the SDK Manager, installed all support software like the ndk,etc. I also downloaded the latest ndk separately. During setting up Android on Qt, I added the SDK directory, the NDK directory, and jre from the Android studio directory. 
[image: Android Devices Window]
The setup seems to be fine.

The kits that I have are
[image]

The android_test.pro

```
QT += quick
CONFIG += c++11

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any Qt feature that has been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Refer to the documentation for the
# deprecated API to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules just for Qt Quick Designer
QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

**@UPDATE:**
I managed to fix the project start up issue. After searching online I found this [chat](https://forum.qt.io/topic/94858/qt-android-problem). According to it, I added ndk version 17. The project got created without problem.

Comment: share the code in `android_test.pro`

Comment: currently, NDK 20 is not usable with the latest version of Qt. Downgrade to 19 and see if that fixes your problem (https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Android_known_issues).

Comment: @RolfWinter, I tried to setup with ndk 19, but it still didn't work.